# (Pseudo-)random array in Bash used as seed in Python simulations

Tags: python, arrays, bash, random

A Bash script controls a Python script ("main.py") which needs a random seed to run.
Aiming at getting several realizations of the simulation, I would like to have a *random* random seed for each of them.

I thought to initialize (in the Bash script) a random array of NEXP integers, but I think not to have done it properly. Indeed, I get a wrong initialization of the array. Here is the code:

```
NEXP=10
array_seed = [$NEXP]
for j in `seq 0 1 $NEXP`; do
    array_seed[$j]=$RANDOM
    echo $array_seed[$j]
done

for A in `seq 0 0.1 1`; do          #A is a parameter of the simulation
    for i in `seq 0 1 $NEXP`; do    #10 realiz. of the process for each A
        SEED=$array_seed[$i]
        ./main.py $A $SEED > output-$A-$i.dat
        done
done
```

and here what I obtained

```
23041[0]
23041[1]
23041[2]
23041[3]
...
```

**Question #1 (solved):** what did I do wrong? And how to put $NEXP - 1 within *seq* to get an array with indexes from 0 to NEXP-1? I tried with the double parentheses put it didn't work.

*Answer (by Ser Jothan Chanes):*

```
NEXP=10
array_seed = [$NEXP]
for i in `seq 0 1 $(($NEXP-1))`; do
    array_seed[$i]=$RANDOM
    echo ${array_seed[$i]}
done
```

**Question #2:** is this a good way to approach the problem of obtaining independent realization of the simulation? And how could I reduce even more the correlation among the simulations/experiments?

**Question #3:** finally, should I deal with the seed of the Bash pseudo-random generator, too?

Thank you!

Comment: Regarding question #3, `bash` `$RANDOM` isn't very (also holds true for `sh`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc.)... And there's not really any effective way to seed it. It may be sufficient for this particular usage, but you're better off using `/dev/[u]random` if it's available, or some other program/library that provides a higher quality PRNG/CRNG for serious simulation/modelling.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me using bash 4.2.45

Q1: Should be kind of ok, as long as the random number generators in bash and python are different.

Q2: what is the question?

Q3: seq 0 1 $(($NEXP-1))

Q4: Reference the array elements by ${array_seed[$i]} (as can be found in the bash manual).

Q5: If you use Linux, you could read 'man urandom'.